# put most of my code in another class how to let it function in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have made a calculator within one class file and it was working fine. 
Now I decided to only let my inputstring and scanner in the main class and remaining code into another class. How to make it works? Please note that I am a beginner. So main class also needs to run / execute the calculator class.

Errors that I receive in calculator class are:

- inputString cannot be resolved to a variable
- Duplicate field calculator.i (my for loops)
- and further a lot of syntax errors about these symbols (,),;,.

***Main class***

```
package com.haynespro.calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class CharAtExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String arg:args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }

        // inputString with scanner

        String inputString = "0";

        inputString = inputString.replace(",", "");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("please insert your calculations: ");

        inputString = user_input.next();

        user_input.close();


        }
    }
}
```

***Calculator class***

```
package com.haynespro.calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Calculator {

    // Assign ArrayList of Strings "res" to splitExpression

    ArrayList<String> res = splitExpression(inputString);

    // Create an ObjectList that holds res

    ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(res);

    System.out.print("\n Let my algorithm take care of it: \n\n");

    // Loop through the objectList and convert strings to doubles

    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        try {
            objectList.set(i, Double.parseDouble((String) objectList.get(i)));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }
    }

    // Create a variable maxi to substract 2 from the objectList index

    int maxi = objectList.size();

    maxi = maxi - 2;

    // Create variable lastSum out of the incoming for-loop's scope.

    double lastSum = 0;

    // Loop through the objectList with an algorhitm and perform calculations with
    // invoking the sum method

    for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i += 2) {
        String operator = (String) objectList.get(i + 1);
        double a = (Double) objectList.get(i);
        double b = (Double) objectList.get(i + 2);
        double sum;

        if (i == 0) {
            sum = sum(a, b, operator);
        } else {
            sum = sum(lastSum, b, operator);
        }
        lastSum = sum;
        System.out.println(lastSum);
    }

    // Method that matches the string input with operators to perform calculations.

    public static double sum(Double a, Double b, String operator) {

        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            return a + b;
        }
        if (operator.equals("-")) {
            return a - b;
        }
        if (operator.equals("*")) {
            return a * b;
        }
        if (operator.equals("/")) {
            return a / b;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // ArrayList splitExpression that casts to inputString

    public static ArrayList<String> splitExpression(String inputString) {

        // ArrayList result to return the result

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Uses the toCharArray method to insert the string reference per character into
        // an array

        char[] destArray = inputString.toCharArray();

        // Empty String created

        String token = "";

        // Iterate through the "Items" in the Array

        for (int i = 0; i < destArray.length; i++) {

            // Nice all those references but we need an Object that actually holds the array

            char c = destArray[i];

            // If not a number then add to token, else assign the value of c to token

            if (isBreakCharacter(c)) {
                result.add(token);
                result.add(Character.toString(c));
                token = "";
            } else
                token = token + c;
            }

            result.add(token);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // a method that breaks characters which are not numbers.The object "c" also
    // needs to hold this method.

    public static boolean isBreakCharacter(char c) {
        return c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '-' || c == '/';
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a method for your code in the class Calculator.

Comment: I did but it is still not working I will show it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the code in a method inside your class. For example:

```
public static void doStuff(String inputString) {
    // Assign ArrayList of Strings "res" to splitExpression
    ArrayList<String> res = splitExpression(inputString);
    // Create an ObjectList that holds res
    ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(res);
    System.out.print("\n Let my algorithm take care of it: \n\n");

    // (...)  REST OF YOUR CODE

    for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i += 2) {
        String operator = (String) objectList.get(i + 1);
        double a = (Double) objectList.get(i);
        double b = (Double) objectList.get(i + 2);
        double sum;

        if (i == 0) {
            sum = sum(a, b, operator);
        } else {
            sum = sum(lastSum, b, operator);
        }
        lastSum = sum;
        System.out.println(lastSum);
    }
}
```

Now, the method `doStuff` has the parameter `String inputString` (which solves your first problem *inputString cannot be resolved to a variable*). All other syntax errors should be gone now as well.

In your `main` method you would call that method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "0";

    // the code with the scanner comes here...

    doStuff(inputString);
}
```

Another hint: Scanner might throw exceptions - so you need to `try.. catch` them. Since you "close" the scanner at the end you can use the shorter *try with resources* which would look like this:

```
try (Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in)) {         // the scanner is only available inside the try block - and in each case (exception or not) it will be closed.
    System.out.print("please insert your calculations: ");
    inputString = user_input.next();
}
```

And *last* hint: In your loop you have a `try...catch` that catches a `NumberFormatException`. It would be best when you handle the exception. For example print a message for the user so he knows what happened or set default numbers...

hope this helps

Comment: allright my 1st problem is solved I still have much problems left most compil errors are still there. He starts to complain now about my splitexpression method that it is undefined for the type Calculator. the method itself says Duplicate local variable inputString and  Illegal modifier for parameter splitExpression; only final is permitted.

Comment: It is working :-) I had to put the } of the new method on the right place

Comment: fantasic! If I where you, I would make the new method return the result (not just print it). This can also help you keep an overviwe of your programs. Usually algortihms have some input and some output - so put that stuff in separate methods and let your main method make the calls one after another.

Comment: I have one more thing if I give args from public static void main(String[] args). How to get this as my inputString so it calculates these arguments automatically? and when no args given he asks for enter something....

Comment: `args` is a `String[]` so when you call `java myProgram hello` from your console, in your main method the `args[0]` will contain the String `"hello"`. But be aware that `args`can be `null` or `empty` or have more than one argument: `java myProgram hello world` (where `args[0]` will be `"hello"` and `args[1]` would be `"world"`)

Comment: What I want to achieve is if I give as an argument 4+4+4 dat he uses that as input to start the calculator immediately and give the answer.

Comment: you already have a method that splits your "inputString". So `args[0]` can be your inputString that you have to split. If you have more problems with that, you should probably ask a new question. The comment section is not the best forum for that :)